# odbc driver syntax error on update statement

Tags: java

```
String sql = "update Products set ProductName = ?, where ID = ? ";
try{
   pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   pst.setString(1, Product.getText());
   pst.setString(2, ID.getText());
            pst.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
            UpdateJTable();
   }
   catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }
```

Please Again Help me Out of this error. why there's an error on my code.? I follow all the instruction on youtube, but i makes an error. i used 6.9 netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

You added a comma at SQL statement which is not valid.

```
String sql = "update Products set ProductName = ?, where ID = ? ";
                                                 |-remove this comma
```

Comment: why on youtube . they have a comma? and its running